# SVN Merge Failing E160013 File not found

Tags: svn, merge, version-control, repository, subdirectory

We have a SVN repository that we have been using for a number of years with a complex folder structure storing multiple projects. We are trying to pull just one subfolder into a new repository that we can manage separately.

In addition, our original SVN repository appears to be corrupted at one of the revision numbers in the middle of the revision history so dumping and loading the full repository fails.

The process we are attempting is as follows:

1. Attempt to create a dump of the repository with only the changes related to the subfolder, after the point of corruption.
2. Attempt to create an empty repository with the folder structure we believe exists prior to the point of corruption.
3. Merge the repository dump (step 1) into a dump of our new empty repository (step 2) to create a merged dump file.
4. Load the merged repository dump file into a new repository that we created freshly.

We are encountering an error when attempting to perform step 4. The following output is received on the bash terminal:

```
------- Committed revision 4308 >>>

<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 4309

------- Committed revision 4309 >>>

<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 4310
     * editing path : Our/Really/Large/Complex/Filepath/Subfolder ...svnadmin: E160013: File not found: transaction '4309-3c9', path '/Our/Really/Large/Complex/Filepath/Subfolder'
```

First, we created the expected folder structure in a new repository "EmptyFolderStructure". This means we added all folders to create the path "/Our/Really/Large/Complex/Filepath/Subfolder" one by one, then used TortoiseSVN to add the folders, then used TortoiseSVN to commit this to the repository.

The full commands we are entering (in bash) are as follows:

Step 1:

```
svnadmin dump repository --revision 4308:8000 > Release4308.8000.dump
svndumpfilter include "Our/Really/Large/Complex/Filepath/Subfolder" < Release4308.8000.dump > Filtered4308.8000.dump
```

Step 2:

```
svnadmin dump EmptyFolderStructure > ResultRepository.dump
```

Step 3:

```
tail -n +4 Release4308.8000.dump >> ResultRepository.dump
```

Step 4:

```
svnadmin create ResultRepository
svnadmin load --ignore-uuid ResultRepository < ResultRepository.dump
```

Has anyone faced a similar problem, and have any ideas for the approach we could take to successfully create the new repository?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

We have managed to get it working. The repository was not corrupted, but attempting to load the dump file failed because it was depending on the pre-existing folder structure. In addition, we needed to move the subfolder to the root folder in order to make this work.

Here were the commands we ended up using:

```
svnadmin dump repository --revision 0:8000 > Release0.8000.dump
svndumpfilter include "Our\Really\Large\Complex\Filepath\Subfolder" < Release0.8000.dump > Filtered0.8000.dump
perl -pi -e 's/Node-path: Our\/Really\/Large\/Complex\/Filepath\//Node-path: /g' Filtered0.8000.dump
perl -pi -e 's/Node-copyfrom-path: Our\/Really\/Large\/Complex\/Filepath\//Node-copyfrom-path: /g' Filtered0.8000.dump
svnadmin create NewRepository
svnadmin load --ignore-uuid NewRepository < Filtered0.8000.dump
```

We were originally using sed for the substitution, however this caused problems with the binary files.